# How to fix "E/WM-SystemJobScheduler: Unable to schedule" error in Android WorkManager with PeriodicWorkRequest?

Tags: android, androidx, android-workmanager, periodic-task

I am trying to setup PeriodicWorkRequest using Work Manager in Android using Android x Library. But Every time i am getting the follwoing exception.

> E/WM-SystemJobScheduler: Unable to schedule {WorkSpec: 8fc2b535-4869-438b-b44e-54e1b4b3507c}
>       java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No such service ComponentInfo{in.dharmalife.dlone/androidx.work.impl.background.systemjob.SystemJobService}
>           at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:1970)
>           at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1934)
>           at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1884)
>           at android.app.job.IJobScheduler$Stub$Proxy.schedule(IJobScheduler.java:184)
>           at android.app.JobSchedulerImpl.schedule(JobSchedulerImpl.java:44)
>           at androidx.work.impl.background.systemjob.SystemJobScheduler.scheduleInternal(SystemJobScheduler.java:182)
>           at androidx.work.impl.background.systemjob.SystemJobScheduler.schedule(SystemJobScheduler.java:128)
>           at androidx.work.impl.Schedulers.schedule(Schedulers.java:92)
>           at androidx.work.impl.utils.EnqueueRunnable.scheduleWorkInBackground(EnqueueRunnable.java:132)
>           at androidx.work.impl.utils.EnqueueRunnable.run(EnqueueRunnable.java:93)
>           at androidx.work.impl.utils.SerialExecutor$Task.run(SerialExecutor.java:91)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)

I did the following things:

1. Add the gradle dependancy.
2. Created the Constraint and PeriodicWorkRequest object and enqueue the request using work manager.

   ```
   public static void storeAttendanceData(Context context, @NotNull AttendanceModel attendanceModel) {

   Constraints myConstraints = new Constraints.Builder()
           .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
           .build();
   PeriodicWorkRequest workRequest = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(AttendanceWorker.class, 1, TimeUnit.HOURS)
           .setConstraints(myConstraints)
           .build();
   WorkManager.getInstance(context).enqueueUniquePeriodicWork("Attendance Worker", ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.REPLACE, workRequest);
   }



    public class AttendanceWorker extends Worker {
          SessionManager sessionManager;

    public AttendanceWorker(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams) {
      super(context, workerParams);
      sessionManager = new SessionManager(context);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Result doWork() {
       makeAttendanceRequest();
       return Result.success();
    }

    private void makeAttendanceRequest() {
       final AttendanceDao attendanceDao = 
       AppDatabase.getDatabase(getApplicationContext()).getAttendanceDao();

       if (attendanceDao.getAllAttendance() != null && attendanceDao.getAllAttendance().length > 0) {
       final String attendanceData = new Gson().toJson(attendanceDao.getAllAttendance());

       Log.e("Complete Attendance ", attendanceData);

       JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, Urls.UPLOAD_ATTENDANCE, attendanceData, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
           @Override
           public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

               Log.e("Attendance Worker -- > ", response.toString());
               Type type = new TypeToken<List<AttendanceModel>>() {
               }.getType();
               ArrayList<AttendanceModel> apiLogsList = new Gson().fromJson(attendanceData, type);
               attendanceDao.deleteAllLogs(apiLogsList);

               Log.e("After Delete Worker--> ", new Gson().toJson(attendanceDao.getAllAttendance()));
           }
       }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
           @Override
           public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
               error.printStackTrace();
           }
       }) {
           @Override
           public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
               Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
               headers.put("Authorization", "JWT " + sessionManager.getSessionToken());
               headers.put("lang", sessionManager.getLanguageId() + "");
               headers.put("language", sessionManager.getSelectedLanguage());
               headers.put("ipAddress", Utils.getLocalIpAddress());
               Log.e("Attendance Headers ", headers.toString());
               return headers;
           }
       };

       request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(30000, 0, 0));
       AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(request);
   }

   }
   }
   ```

i expect the request should work but its thrown as exception

> E/WM-SystemJobScheduler: Unable to schedule {WorkSpec: 8fc2b535-4869-438b-b44e-54e1b4b3507c}
>       java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No such service ComponentInfo{in.dharmalife.dlone/androidx.work.impl.background.systemjob.SystemJobService}
>           at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:1970)
>           at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1934)
>           at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1884)
>           at android.app.job.IJobScheduler$Stub$Proxy.schedule(IJobScheduler.java:184)
>           at android.app.JobSchedulerImpl.schedule(JobSchedulerImpl.java:44)
>           at androidx.work.impl.background.systemjob.SystemJobScheduler.scheduleInternal(SystemJobScheduler.java:182)
>           at androidx.work.impl.background.systemjob.SystemJobScheduler.schedule(SystemJobScheduler.java:128)
>           at androidx.work.impl.Schedulers.schedule(Schedulers.java:92)
>           at androidx.work.impl.utils.EnqueueRunnable.scheduleWorkInBackground(EnqueueRunnable.java:132)
>           at androidx.work.impl.utils.EnqueueRunnable.run(EnqueueRunnable.java:93)
>           at androidx.work.impl.utils.SerialExecutor$Task.run(SerialExecutor.java:91)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)

Comment: What does your merged manifest look like?

Comment: @SumirKodes
<manifest
    <application android:name="AppController">
        <provider
            android:name="androidx.work.impl.WorkManagerInitializer"
            android:authorities="in.dharmalife.dlone.workmanager-init"
            android:enabled="true" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Splash">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>

Comment: You're missing a bunch of WorkManager services and broadcast receivers.  (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev/work/workmanager/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml)  That's why you're getting this error.  You should look into why they're not getting merged properly.

Comment: @SumirKodes this worked. Thanks

Comment: @SumirKodes is there any documentation to we should init these services and broadcast receivers. in our Manifest file?

Comment: You shouldn't need to do any of that. By default, all of these components are enabled. I'm not sure what happened in the case of OP's app.

Comment: @SumirKodes in my case these components are not enabled. Don't know why.

Comment: @ArihantJain #SumirKodes Please share the approach that works for you.